# java ArrayList initial capacity performance effect

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have in my java app a loop that adds object arrays into a list

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

I noticed that NOT giving an initial capacity was actually faster than giving the capacity.

I have a 23 seconds  vs 15 seconds difference.

I've created this dummy JUnit test to mock that and go 6 seconds vs 6.7 seconds difference, favoring the NO initial capacity:

```
@Test
public void asdf() {

    int rowSize = 20;
    int rowCount = 10000000;

    // DATA PREP
    int[][] matrix = new int[rowCount][];
    for (int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++) {

        matrix[i] = new int[rowSize];
        for (int j=0; j< rowSize; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }

    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Object> getValue = new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(Integer row, Integer col) {
            return matrix[row][col];
        }
    };

    //END DATA PREP

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // THIS IS THE DIFFERENCE!!!!
    //List<Object[]> lst = new ArrayList<>(rowCount);
    List<Object[]> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        Object[] row = new Object[rowSize];

        for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; j++) {
            row[j] = getValue.apply(i, j);
        }

        lst.add(row);
    }

    long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    System.out.println(totalTime);
}
```

How does it make any sense?

I know generally this code is crap, It's just trying to mock my real case, reading off a resultset (not the jdbc one).

Thanks!

Comment: This is **not** a proper benchmark.

Comment: Micro benchmarks are tricky in Java. You are better off profiling the actual code you are worried about rather than ArrayList specific performance. It sounds like you are dealing with IO and this is certain to be a bigger limitation than ArrayList on performance.